# Combining two columns to other two columns, sharing same first column data but not sharing all rows data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, concatenation

How to join the data of two columns to another two columns, they both have the same first column name, but they dont share all the same rows data in Excel.

The rows are not so litte, to do that manually.

The result should be so as illustrated in the lower part of the figure:

[figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rWgq.jpg)

Comment: You should search for this on here and on stack overflow - it will likely be closed as a duplicate...

Comment: I have searched on here, no so question, but I will post it there on stack overflow

Comment: then, when you do remove this question and show your input and expected output.

Comment: I am new here, I need 90 min to post again

Comment: SO will probably tell him to post here.  Khaled, I will give you a formula for the first part of the solution you need.  Fill this formula down from C11 in your example sheet:  `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A3,C$2:C$5,0)),"",A3)`.  Now use a similar formula, but with [VLOOKUP()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) replacing [MATCH()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-match-function) to generate your second column starting in D11.  You can follow the links to learn more about these two functions.  If you run into problems, EDIT your question and show what you have tried.